Get the parameters from an outlook uri scheme
I have this outlook uri scheme.
Example: ms-outlook://folders/inbox?code=1234
It will open the outlook app in my desktop, which is working fine.
I have a custom add-in, i want to get the code parameter into my taskpane.js, How i can do that ?
